# Aggregate Initialization Branch Coverage

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, code-coverage, gcov

I am building a [tool](https://github.com/RPGillespie6/fastcov) that is essentially an alternative to lcov. I am trying to make the default branch coverage it generates have as little noise as possible. One source of branch noise seems to be initializer lists:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct A {
   vector<string> reference_tokens;
};

int main() {
  A a;

  vector<string> rt = {"a", "b", "c"};

  a.reference_tokens = {rt[0]};
  return 0;
}
```

When I generate coverage for this snippet, I get:

```
 9                 :            : struct A {
10                 :            :    vector<string> reference_tokens;
11                 :            : };
12                 :            : 
13                 :          1 : int main() {
14                 :          2 :   A a;
15                 :            : 
16 [ +  - ][ +  - ]:          6 :   vector<string> rt = {"a", "b", "c"};
   [ +  - ][ +  - ]
17                 :            : 
18 [ +  - ][ +  - ]:          2 :   a.reference_tokens = {rt[0]};
   [ +  + ][ -  - ]
19                 :          1 :   return 0;
20                 :            : }
```

Now, I realize GCC inserts branches for handling exceptions. However, if I filter out exceptional branches, I'm still left with:

```
 9                 :            : struct A {
10                 :            :    vector<string> reference_tokens;
11                 :            : };
12                 :            : 
13                 :          1 : int main() {
14                 :          2 :   A a;
15                 :            : 
16                 :          6 :   vector<string> rt = {"a", "b", "c"};
17                 :            : 
18 [ +  + ][ -  - ]:          2 :   a.reference_tokens = {rt[0]};
19                 :          1 :   return 0;
20                 :            : }
```

I'm not sure what these 4 branches `[ +  + ][ -  - ]` are for. They are not exceptional branches according to gcov, and it seems they always are 1:1. For example, a bigger initializer list will result in `[ +  + ][ +  + ][ +  + ][ -  - ][ -  - ][ -  - ]` non-exceptional branches.

So my question is... what are these branches? Are the reachable? Are they noise that can be safely removed?